# changing default download location in chrome using Python selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want to download files into a desired location in chrome using python selenium.however,i am not getting any idea.our framework uses mozwebqa.
how do i change the properties to download files to my desired location.

Just a sample code

```
   @pytest.fixture()
def preparation (self, request, mozwebqa):
    openyaml = open("desired txt file")
    testdata = yaml.load(openyaml)
    openyaml.close()
    self.sample = testdata['abc']

def test_sampletest(self, mozwebqa, preparation):
    homepage = basePage(mozwebqa).homepage()
    homepage.login()
```

please help, where to set the preference for downloading files to my desired location.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code :-

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/some/path"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Source: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: Thanks Shubham,but its not working for me.Actually I am not getting how to use it with mozwebqa